# How to run Mugsy multiple alignment software on Linux Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: bioinformatics

How to run Mugsy software on Linux Ubuntu 11.04?

I can`t run it as written in instructions
How to cset up .sh file?
Here is my effort to set it up:
 - #!/bin/sh export MUGSY_INSTALL=./mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.1 export  PATH=$PATH:$MUGSY_INSTALL:$MUGSY_INSTALL/mapping export
   PERL5LIB=$MUGSY_INSTALL/perllibs export
   MUGSY_INSTALL=/media/44D2-B182/Mugsy_BOOKS_Are_Here_July_25/mugsy.
   #For testing TBA
   #export PATH=$PATH:$MUGSY_INSTALL/../../multiz-tba/trunk/
   #export PATH=$PATH:$MUGSY_INSTALL/home/samsung/saitdlyafirmi/mugsy/
   #export MUGSY_INSTALL=/home/samsung/saitdlyafirmi/mugsy/
Then I run source mugsyenv.sh and nothing happens

Comment: `Then I run source mugsyenv.sh and nothing happens` - Well what did you expect from sourcing this file?

Comment: You say that now I can run Mugsy? I thought it could say something that software is installed